# Why can we equate these two integrals related to blackbody radiation?

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency, integration, wavelength, calculus

I was reading [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) which describes how Planck’s Law of blackbody radiation is derived. Letting $B(v,T)$ represent the energy emitted at frequency $v$ and temperature $T$, the article states that we may “[equate] the integral of spectral radiance in per unit wavelength to that of per unit frequency” like this:

$$\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} B(\lambda,T)d\lambda=\int_{v(\lambda_1)}^{v(\lambda_2)}B(v,T)dv$$

From here, we can easily solve for $B$ by converting the above equality into a differential equation.

**My question is**: why is this equation true in the first place? Why is it a valid assumption that “the integral of spectral radiance in per unit wavelength [equals] that of per unit frequency?” What property of radiation implies that this must be true?

Comment: Minor comment: That should be a Greek letter $\nu$, not a Roman letter $v$.

Answer (score 3):

The amount of radiance in an interval of the electromagnetic spectrum is the same regardless of whether that spectral interval is described in terms of a range of wavelengths or a range of frequencies. For example, if you asked how much radiance is in green light, it’s the same whether you define green as being 500-565 nm or 530-600 THz. These are the same spectral interval.

Answer (score 3):

These are the *definitions* of the two spectral radiances. $B(\lambda, T)$ is defined by stating that the intensity emitted between wavelengths $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is

$$I = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} B(\lambda, T)\ d\lambda, $$

and similarly for $B(\nu, T)$. Or, in physicist language, the intensity in a small interval $d\lambda$ is $B(\lambda, T)\ d\lambda$. Therefore, we have two different formulas for the intensity emitted between two wavelengths or between their corresponding frequencies, and so the formulas have to be the same.